# Is there a "Vue way" to check for empty string variables other than if/else statements?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Im learning how to use Vue and having trouble wrapping my head around the "vue" way to do things.

Is there a Vue function or method i can use to not have to write so many statements?

```
    this.catArr = []

    if (cat === 'All Modules') {
      if (this.assetType !== '') {
        this.catArr.push(this.assetType)
      }
      if (this.assetFormat !== '') {
        this.catArr.push(this.assetFormat)
      }
      if (this.assetUse !== '') {
        this.catArr.push(this.assetUse)
      }
      this.catArr.push(this.assetMod)
    } else if (cat === 'All Types') {
      if (this.assetMod !== '') {
        this.catArr.push(this.assetMod)
      }
      if (this.assetFormat !== '') {
        this.catArr.push(this.assetFormat)
      }
      if (this.assetUse !== '') {
        this.catArr.push(this.assetUse)
      }
      this.catArr.push(this.assetType)
    } else {
      if (this.assetMod !== '') {
        this.catArr.push(this.assetMod)
      }
      if (this.assetType !== '') {
        this.catArr.push(this.assetType)
      }
      if (this.assetFormat !== '') {
        this.catArr.push(this.assetFormat)
      }
      if (this.assetUse !== '') {
        this.catArr.push(this.assetUse)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Does it have to be a Vue method? It would be really simple to achieve this in vanilla JS

Comment: it does not have to be Vue - but since im learning vue it would be nice to know if there was a built in way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find a "Vue" way in my research but i was able to simplify the logic.

```
   this.catArr = []

    if (this.assetType !== '') {
      this.catArr.push(this.assetType)
    }
    if (this.assetFormat !== '') {
      this.catArr.push(this.assetFormat)
    }
    if (this.assetUse !== '') {
      this.catArr.push(this.assetUse)
    }
    if (this.assetMod !== '') {
      this.catArr.push(this.assetMod)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In vanilla JS, it's easy to accomplish this by writing [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) code. Define all properties upfront, define the properties to explicitly test *for each category*, and when it comes time to create the array, just iterate over the property names and test them accordingly:

```
const props = ['assetType', 'assetFormat', 'assetUse', 'assetMod'];
const catPropsNotToTest = {
  'All Modules': ['assetMod'],
  'All Types': ['assetType'],
  default: [],
};

// ...

const propsNotToTest = catPropsNotToTest[cat] ? catPropsNotToTest[cat] : catPropsNotToTest.default;
this.catArr = props.reduce((propArr, propName) => {
  if (propsNotToTest.includes(propName)) propArr.push(this[propName]);
  else if (this[propName] !== '') propArr.push(this[propName]);
  return propArr;
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot CP, maybe i was too deep in Vue to think in vanilla JS